# Can wakelock affect the Android state?

Tags: android

A bad thing happened to me today. The Samsung Galaxy S4 of my boss broken while he was using my app, he slept while app was running and in the morning when he woke up the cell phone just died (He can't turn it on).

So I tried to figure out if something that I did in code could have done it, and the only thing that I can suppose is the use of wakelock. After read the Documentation about wakelock I've found that it can modify the screen states but I thought if something happened when the android was restarted wakelock states would be reset. Is it?

So someone can help me to figure out if should I start to find another job, or it was just an unfortunate coincidence ??

Comment: This is off topic here. You might try [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) or [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The battery probably died because it was awake all night :D. Can't think of a reason why it won't start with a few minutes on charge. I'd blame it on Samsung and move on, unless anyone has some bright ideas.

Comment: @SamarthJain it's not battery, we charged it many times, with diferent chargers and nothing

Comment: @Undo even with the jokes, I'm still asking about WAKELOCK

Comment: @VictorOliveira This would still probably be better on-topic on Android.

Comment: @Undo - no, the valid part of the asked question is a programming question not a usage one, so it belongs here rather than there.  Trying to fix the device however would belong there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Edit out the last sentence, then?

Comment: The last sentence isn't valid on the Android site either, I think it's easiest to ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wakelock can make it drain the battery to 0 very quickly, but it can't harm the hardware.  When you eventually run out of juice, the device would turn off until you recharged it, but upon restart there would be no wakelock (they do not persist across reboots).  SO if the device won't turn on after leaving it plugged in for half an hour or so, something else is going on.

And if you're actually in danger of losing your job for destroying 1 device, your boss is an idiot.  It will cost way more than $600 to replace a developer.  I've broken $20K prototypes and gotten no more than a couple of annoyed MechEs glaring at me.